# How to unset specific data array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

Its been two days I'm working with these guys. Need help here.

here is my view

```
$username = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), TRUE);

    foreach ($username AS $key => $value) {

    <?php echo $value['username']; ?>
    <?php echo $value['firstname']; ?>
    <?php echo $value['lastname']; ?>
    <?php $u = $value['username']; ?>
    <?php echo "<a href=".base_url()."index.php/bets/un_sess/$u /> X </a> " ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

here is my controller

```
$user1 = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), TRUE);
 foreach ($user AS $key => $value) {
       $index = array_search($username, $user);
       unset($user[$index]);          
      $this->session->set_userdata('users', $user);
```

array from user_data

```
{"username":"user1","firstname":"name1","lastname":"name2"},
{"username":"user2","firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}
```

the output of this is when the first time i click the
username its working but when i click another username it   gives error like this

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
>
> Filename: libraries/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 433 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: controllers/bets.php
>
> Line Number: 290

Comment: look at your controller, you are storing json_decoded data in `$user1` and then using `$user` in foreach

Comment: when i change that $user1 to $user it gives error like this
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: controllers/bets.php

Line Number: 288

Comment: Here is my answer  $user = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), TRUE);
     foreach ($user AS $key => $value) {
          if ($username == $value['username']){
      // $array_items = array('username' => $value['username'], 'firstname' => $value['firstname'],'lastname' => $value['lastname'] );
          unset($user[$key]);
   }
  }

    $this->session->set_userdata('users', json_encode($user));

Answer (score 0):

ok since there is no answering in my questions. Here is my solutions

```
 $user = json_decode($this->session->userdata('users'), TRUE);
        foreach ($user AS $key => $value) {
          if ($username == $value['username']){

          unset($user[$key]);
         }
        }

       $this->session->set_userdata('users', json_encode($user));
```